# Laravel: Which relationship to use?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have the following scenario:

I'm building a site where Artists show their favorite spots in a city.
So:
There are some `Cities` and some `Artists`. A City `hasMany` `Spots`.
`Artists` and `Spots` also are related together via `belongsToMany`, because one `Spot` could have been featured by multiple `Artists`.

I now want to define a relation in City that gives me all the artists that have something featured in that City (so basically look for artists that are related to a spot from that City)

Is there a relationship type that I can use?
I've tried `hasManyThrough` but that's looking up `spot_id` in `Artist` which is obviously not existent because Artist<>Spot is many to many.

Answer (score 1):

when you have relationship many to many you need to do normalisation for both table, create new table to store spot_id and artist_id. I think in laravel already handle that. This link might be helpful

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/resolve-your-many-to-manys-for-accurate-requirements

Answer (score 0):

Though it's many to many relationship so you have to use `belongsToMany` 
Ex:

In city Model :

```
class City extends Model{
      public function artists(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Artist')
      }
}
```

In Artist Model :

```
class Artist extends Model{
      public function city(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\City')
      }
}
```

Comment: This won't work in my case, because Artists aren't directly connected to a City. They are through the Spot Model (A spot belongs to a City; Spot and Artist are related via manyToMany relationship)

Comment: So in city model you can give relationship with spots and in spot model you can give relationship wih artists so whenever you want to use you can use it as spots.artists